# В MVC как соединить событие через View и добавление в Module?

Tags: javascript, ооп, mvc, ecmascript-6

Собственно весь вопрос в заголовке, у меня есть кнопка написана через HTML, есть View и есть Module с пустым массивом, как через Controller я по клику могу добавить что либо в массив модуля, допустим вот моя View, которая возвращает число:

```
export class View {

    addItem() {
        let plus = document.querySelector('.plus');
        plus.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let num = document.querySelector('.count').innerHTML;
            return num;
        })
    }
}
```

Вот мой Модуль с функцией addNum, которая собственно и должна добавлять число в массив:

```
export class Module {
    constructor() {
        this.num = [];
    }


    addNum(num){
        this.num.push(num);
    }

}
```

А вот Controller:

```
class Controller {
    constructor(view, module){
        this.view = view;
this.module = module;
    }

    getNum(){
        this.cart.addNum(this.view.addItem());

    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я вызываю функцию контроллера getNum, она срабатывает моментально, как мне дождаться какого либо события ?
Надеюсь все ясно объяснил, спасибо!

Comment: Как вариант обернуть это «что-то» в промис, и от туда вызывать действия контроллера? Ну а вообще конечно, вы что, не знаете когда вам надо вызывать контроллер?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, я сначала напрямую в контроллере добавлял событие, но насколько я понимаю, в контроллере вообще ничего не должно быть связанно с DOM. Поэтому, каюсь, не знаю, и буду очень благодарен если приведете пример, как правильно связать View и Module с помощью Controller`а. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Все проще чем вы думаете. Происходит некоторое событие, вы вызывает контроллер, контроллер делает некоторые действия, и вызывает `view` Чтобы тот нарисовал нам страницу, при этом может передавать туда какие-то данные. При этом, контроллер перед тем как рисовать вид(или после) может делать запрос к модели, на которую ложиться основная логика(запросы на сервер, сохранения и т.д). Модель может(но это не обязательно) возвращать контроллеру какие-то данные, чтобы тот передал их в `view`.

Вот таким образом обычно идёт связывания `model, view, controller`.